# How can I access iron:router params from an event?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

```
Router.map ->
  @route '/foo'

Template.foo.events
  'click something': ->
    Router.current().params #is empty array

Router.go '/foo', thenGoTo: 'bar'
```

I want to access the `thenGoTo: 'bar'` object.

I could do `Router.go 'foo', {} {query: 'thenGoTo=bar'}` and then parse `Router.current().url`, but I'd rather keep a clean URL.

Comment: Using your code, you can get it directly with `Router.current().params.query.thenGoTo`. If you use params, you have to declare them in the route (`/foo/:thenGoTo`), but that also sticks the value in the URL, and frankly looks more confusing. Those are the only two solutions I found.

Comment: `Router.current().params` is supposed to be an array, so [.query shouldn't work, yet it does](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1213). Agree that transmitting variables via the URL is ugly. [Reactive state variables](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#setting-reactive-state-variables) might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks David, for some reason my `.params` is emptied at some point between `onBeforeAction` and the handler, but `.params.query` works. Dan, there's no way to set the state variable from the `.go` call, right? Maybe I could put it in the param/query string in the `.go` call and then remove it from the URL and put it in the state in `onBeforeAction`.